# AdMob interstitial ad only shown once react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, admob

```
import { InterstitialAd, AdEventType, TestIds } from '@react-native-firebase/admob';

const adUnitId = __DEV__ ? TestIds.INTERSTITIAL : 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyyyyyy';

const interstitial = InterstitialAd.createForAdRequest(adUnitId, {
  requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
  keywords: ['fashion', 'clothing'],
});

function App() {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const eventListener = interstitial.onAdEvent(type => {
      if (type === AdEventType.LOADED) {
        setLoaded(true);
      }
    });

    // Start loading the interstitial straight away
    interstitial.load();

    // Unsubscribe from events on unmount
    return () => {
      eventListener();
    };
  }, []);

  // No advert ready to show yet
  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Button
      title="Show Interstitial"
      onPress={() => {
        interstitial.show();
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

When I click the button for the first time, the ad is shown. But when I again click the button it'll throw me an error.

**Error: firebase.admob().InterstitialAd.show() The requested Interstitial Ad hasnt been loaded and could not be shown.**

How can I solve this? I want to show an ad every time I click on the button.

Answer (score 6):

```
import {
  InterstitialAd,
  AdEventType,
  TestIds
} from '@react-native-firebase/admob';

const adUnitId = __DEV__
  ? TestIds.INTERSTITIAL
  : 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyyyyyy';

const interstitialAd = InterstitialAd.createForAdRequest(adUnitId);

export default class App extends Component {

componentDidMount() {

    interstitialAd.onAdEvent(type => {
      if (type === AdEventType.LOADED) {
        console.log('InterstitialAd adLoaded');
      } else if (type === AdEventType.ERROR) {
        console.warn('InterstitialAd => Error');
      } else if (type === AdEventType.OPENED) {
        console.log('InterstitialAd => adOpened');
      } else if (type === AdEventType.CLICKED) {
        console.log('InterstitialAd => adClicked');
      } else if (type === AdEventType.LEFT_APPLICATION) {
        console.log('InterstitialAd => adLeft_App');
      } else if (type === AdEventType.CLOSED) {
        console.log('InterstitialAd => adClosed');
        interstitialAd.load();
      }
    });

interstitialAd.load();

}

showAd() {
    if (interstitialAd.loaded) {
      interstitialAd.show().catch(error => console.warn(error));
    }
  }

render() {
    return (

     <Button
       title="Show Interstitial"
       onPress={() => {
         this.showAd();
      }}
    />

)}
```

This is actually a snippet from a production code - ENJOY!